# Make npm start script run ng serve in a particular port

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I have some scripts in my `package.json`, and I need to know how to get the `start` script to correctly accept the `-port` parameter for angular-cli.

```
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve  --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
```

We need this because we would like to run multiple instances of our software simultaneously. Currently, if I have one project running on the default port 4200, and try to run `npm start -port 4300` in a second terminal window, I get, "Port 4200 is already in use. Use '--port' to specify a different port."

What can I do to get my build to run in a particular port? And how can I make it so that I can pass the port number into the npm start script from the command line?

Comment: Maybe it's a little thing but `-port` and `--port` are two different things. Check for typos.

Comment: are you using angular-cli

Comment: Yes I am using angular-cli. @tadman, I've tried both --port and -port.

Comment: You may need to put `--port` in the `start` section here, that `npm start` won't pass that through as you expect.

Comment: Ok, what would that look like?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

If you add "--" the parameters are passed through:

```
npm start -- --port 4301
```

Comment: It should be noted that this is only part of the solution and is in addition to Sajeetharan's answer. @Sajeetharan's answer deserves upvotes as well.

Answer (score 6):

Change it as,

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --port 4301",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
```

Comment: Ok, that's simple. But how would I make it so that I can pass the port number into the npm start script from the command line?

Comment: try this ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4301

Comment: Specifically looking for the ability to say npm start -port XXXX, to use whatever port I pass in the command line.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this command

`ng serve --port 4400`

`npm start -- --port 4400`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this command:

```
npm run start -- -p 4300
```